# sum the column in table not produce correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
SUM(p.mc_gross) AS totalsales,
SUM(p.tax) AS totlatax, 
(SELECT SUM(totalamount) FROM table1 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(paydate, '%d-%m-%Y') = 
    DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS totalagentsales, 
DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS filter,
(p.mc_gross - p.tax - (SELECT SUM(totalamount) FROM table1)) AS TotalRevenue,
(p.tax + (SELECT SUM(totalamount) FROM table1) ) AS TotalPayment
FROM table2 AS p GROUP BY filter LIMIT 0, 30
```

This query sum will not produce the correct result. I did subtraction for `TotalRevenue` and addition for `TotalPayment`. This result is not correct.

This is my output:

```
totalsales  totlatax   totalagentsales   filter       TotalRevenue   TotalPayment
38.99       3.54       NULL              11-03-2011   33.152         4.54
6           0.09       NULL              14-02-2011   3.612          1.09
2177.46     197.96     0.899             14-03-2011   1977.202       198.96
299.94      27.27      1.399             15-03-2011   270.372        28.27
19.98       1.82       NULL              21-01-2011   15.862         2.82
3           0.27       NULL              22-01-2011   0.432          1.27
14.77       1.82       NULL              28-02-2011   10.652         2.82
```

Comment: the question needs more explanation

Comment: please tell me what i want to explain..
 Date wise payment entry will come more then one times in table i will pick up date wise date want to come in output only one time

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about the layout of your tables, the data in your tables, nor what you expect vs. what you have, I'm just guessing here. First, you probably need to repeat the use of `SUM` for the other instances where you access `mc_gross` and `tax`. Also, I think your use of subqueries is messing you up, in particular the two instances of `SELECT SUM(totalamount) FROM table1`. I imagine you want to limit the rows used in the calculation of these sums similarly to how you do with `totalagentsales`. You can reuse the `totalagentsales` value if you move it into the `FROM` clause as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(p.mc_gross) AS totalsales, SUM(p.tax) AS totlatax, 
       q.totalagentsales, DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS filter,
       (SUM(p.mc_gross) - SUM(p.tax) - q.totalagentsales) AS TotalRevenue,
       (SUM(p.tax) + q.totalagentsales) AS TotalPayment
FROM table2 AS p,
     (SELECT SUM(totalamount) totalagentsales FROM table1
      WHERE DATE_FORMAT(paydate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
     ) AS q
GROUP BY filter 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT SUM(p.mc_gross) AS totalsales, SUM(p.tax) AS totlatax, 
       q.totalagentsales, DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS filter,
       (SUM(p.mc_gross) - SUM(p.tax) - q.totalagentsales) AS TotalRevenue,
       (SUM(p.tax) + q.totalagentsales) AS TotalPayment
FROM table2 AS p
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(totalamount) totalagentsales,
                       DATE_FORMAT(paydate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS filter
                FROM table1 GROUP BY filter) AS q
               ON DATE_FORMAT(p.payment_date, '%d-%m-%Y') = q.filter
GROUP BY filter 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: For Your Reply thanks
p.payment_date  unknown column error came

Comment: @Mohan, sorry, it seems that references to columns in table on the outer query is a no-no... ^^; Try the edit.